# Value already read, or no value when trying to read from a Stream

Tags: c#, decode, minecraft

I've been trying this for a long time but it keeps giving me an error. I have an array of bytes that should represent a nbt document. I would like to convert this into a c# object with a library: fNbt.

Here is my code:

```
byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
byte[] decompressed;

using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
{
    using var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

    using (var gzip = new GZipStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, leaveOpen: true))
    {
        gzip.CopyTo(outputStream);
    }

    fNbt.NbtReader reader = new fNbt.NbtReader(outputStream, true);
    var output = reader.ReadValueAs<AuctionItem>(); //Error: Value already read, or no value to read.
    return output;
}
```

When I try this, it works:

```
            decompressed = outputStream.ToArray();
            outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            outputStream.Read(new byte[1000], 0, decompressed.Count() - 1);
```

But when I try this, it doesn't:

```
            outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            fNbt.NbtReader reader = new fNbt.NbtReader(outputStream, true);
            reader.ReadValueAs<AuctionItem>();
```

Comment: Is this question good enough or not? Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: *"it does not seem to work"* is not a problem description, and that's the only reason anyone posts here so that's just noise. If that's the exception message in the comment, it's not very visible. That really should be the title so that anyone else having this issue can find it.

Comment: This site is a wiki and your question is an article about the issue you're having. When the issue is an exception, that should be the focal point of the post. Why you wrote the code may be important to you, but less so for future readers with the same problem (who may be dealing with the same problem for entirely different reasons).

Comment: Anyway, my crystal ball says that `outputStream` needs to be reset to the beginning. You just wrote to it and the current position is now at the end. `NbtReader` has nothing to read if it's at the end.

Comment: How can I fix this!?!?!? Also I will remake the title, and i just reailized I am retardd

Answer (score 0):

`NbtReader`, like most stream readers, begins reading from the *current* position of whatever stream you give it. Since you're just done writing to `outputStream`, then that position is the stream's end. Which means at that point there's nothing to be read.

The solution is to *seek* the `outputStream` back to the beginning before reading from it:

```
outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // <-- seek to the beginning    

// Do the read
fNbt.NbtReader reader = new fNbt.NbtReader(outputStream, true);
var output = reader.ReadValueAs<AuctionItem>(); // No error anymore
return output;
```

Comment: Side note: I tend to use `outputStream.Position = 0;` as a simpler way of rewinding streams.

Comment: @JonSkeet I got so used to seeking using `Seek` that I don't even think about using `Position` anymore.

Comment: @Etienne de Martal I think you solved a part of the issue but theres more. Please watch my edit if you would want to help more.

Comment: After looking at the source code, the problem is that `NbtReader` only considers certain data types as "values". Those would be scalars and arrays of scalars, but not compounds or lists. `ReadValueAs` is not designed to convert compound tags to arbitrary model classes. It's not as sophisticated as JSON.NET is. Using this answer (and not the other stuff you added to the question), call `ReadAsTag` and cast to `NbtCompound`. You'll need to convert to your `AuctionItem` model class separately.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was about give up with the project because I have been searching for so long. Now I realise, giving up is not an option :D.

Comment: IT WORKS YOU LEGEND

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows. NbtReader.ReadValueAs does not consider a nbtCompound or nbtList as value. I made this little reader but it is not done yet (I will update the code once it is done).

```
    public static T ReadValueAs<T>(string value) where T: new()
    {
        byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(value);

        using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            using var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

            using (var gzip = new GZipStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, leaveOpen: true))
            {
                gzip.CopyTo(outputStream);
            }
            outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            return new EasyNbt.NbtReader(outputStream).ReadValueAs<T>();
        }
    }
```

This is the NbtReader:

```
    private MemoryStream MemStream { get; set; }

    public NbtReader(MemoryStream memStream)
    {
        MemStream = memStream;
    }

    public T ReadValueAs<T>() where T: new()
    {
        return ReadTagAs<T>(new fNbt.NbtReader(MemStream, true).ReadAsTag());
    }

    private T ReadTagAs<T>(fNbt.NbtTag nbtTag)
    {
        //Reads to the root and adds to T...
    }
```